# Angular after module has been loaded

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, all lazy feature modules are preloaded.

Before navigating to a specific route, I would like to know if the feature module linked to the route has been yet fully loaded.

Is there any way to resolve if feature module has been already preloaded?

Comment: The lazy modules are preloaded? What is the sense of that?

Comment: In my main module I want to to magics after all lazy modules are pre-loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your main module loads, all pre-loaded modules start loading. So whenever you load any other route which is pre-loaded you don't need to check whether it is loaded or not.

For more detail Information read this: 
[Preloading Stratergy](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-blocks-preload)

Comment: Is there still any way to check if the pre-loading has been completed?
In e.g. case where I want to do magics in the main module after pre-loading has been done.